# I am trying to launch driverlessai on a local Ubuntu machine

Tags: driverless-ai

I am not clear what they are looking for as server in the instruction
"After Driverless AI is installed and started, open a browser and navigate to :12345."

Based on another answer I tried using localhost and like that answer I could navigate to localhost:54321 (which was "flow") but not localhost:12335.

I also tried going to the machine listed by the hostname command.

In both cases the browser said "refused to connect"

Comment: What package type did you install and how did you start Driverless AI?  You will need to look at the logs, and where you find them depends on the method you chose.

Comment: complete ubuntu dai instructions can be found here: http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/install/ubuntu.html

Comment: Thanks Lauren and Tom! I should have specified it was the deb package that I installed. I started Driverless AI using systemctl and I have looked at the logs. I believe I have found the server address it wants but now my issue is that it is the browser is timing out. The machine is not desperately new, there is 8GB of RAM and the Chip is IntelCorei7CPU m 620 @2.67 GHz x 4, in case it is a hardware issue.

Comment: @JoeBurger would you mind posting the solution you found to your original question? As for the hanging issue, I think you need more memory please see the sizing requirements here: http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/installing.html ... for deb we recommend system CPU memory of 64 GB as a minimum.

Comment: @Lauren The problem seems to be that there was a mismatch between the host name and the hosts shown in /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts and the name that DAI was trying to use. I saw the mismatch by using sudo journalctl dai-procsy. However, the named host it was DAI was looking for appeared not to work either (the time out issue). I finally solved it by pointing at 127.0.1.1:12345 I had tried that previously but used localhost (127.0.0.1:12345) by mistake. I spotted the error using sudo geddit /etc/hosts /etc/hostname. I think this is broadly a story of me being an idiot! Anyway it works fine now

Comment: should have read sudo journalctl -u dai-procsy

Answer (score 0):

reposting Joe's solution (from the comments) for his issue in case it is helpful for others.

- "The problem seems to be that there was a mismatch between the host
  name and the hosts shown in /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts and the name
  that DAI was trying to use. I saw the mismatch by using sudo
  journalctl dai-procsy. However, the named host it was DAI was looking
  for appeared not to work either (the time out issue). I finally
  solved it by pointing at 127.0.1.1:12345 I had tried that previously
  but used localhost (127.0.0.1:12345) by mistake. I spotted the error
  using sudo geddit /etc/hosts /etc/hostname."